# Create Custom Matrix From String

Tags: c, matrix

I want to split the following string:

```
9 0.1 10 0.2 5 1.3 400 0.4 53 0.5 6 0.6
```

And create a matrix 2XN that demonstrate a function for example from A(source) to B(range).

```
9  |  10 | 5  |400 | 53 | 6

0.1| 0.2 |1.3 |0.4 |0.5 | 0.6
```

what I did so far is:

```
char *substring(char *string, int position, int length) 
{
   char *pointer;
   int c;

   pointer = (char *)malloc(length+1);

   if (pointer == NULL)
   {
      printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   for (c = 0 ; c < position -1 ; c++) 
      string++; 

   for (c = 0 ; c < length ; c++)
   {
      *(pointer+c) = *string;      
      string++;   
   }

   *(pointer+c) = '\0';

   return pointer;
}

void fillMatrix(int **functionC,int rows, int cols , char *Text){
    int head=0;
    int tail=0;
    int index=0;
    int i=0,j=0;

    while(Text[index]!='\0')
    {
        if(Text[index]==' ')
        {
            head=index+1;
            //printf("tail %d, head %d \n",tail,head);
            printf("%s",substring(Text,tail,(head-tail)));
            tail=head;

        }
        printf("\n");
        index+=1;


    }


}
```

fillMatrix function should fill the functionC matrix as I mentioned a the begin.
till now its just cuting the string.

1. There is another way to do that? better then that?
2. I would like to get some suggestions how I can achieve that.

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly the same but can give you ideas.
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zig-zag_matrix

Comment: type of functionC matrix as  int?

Comment: yes, but I think I should change it.., the important thing is to insert the numbers in the order to the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

size_t item_count(const char *text, size_t *length){
    size_t count=0, len=0;
    const char *p;
    bool isSpace = true;//start from not item

    for(p=text; *p ;++p, ++len){
        if(isspace(*p)){
            isSpace = true;
        } else if(isSpace){
            isSpace = false;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    if(length && !*length)
        *length = len;
    return count;
}

double **fillMatrix(int *cols, const char *Text){
    size_t items, len =0;
    items = item_count(Text, &len);
    *cols = items / 2;
    double **array = malloc(2* sizeof(double*));
    array[0] = calloc(*cols, sizeof(double));
    array[1] = calloc(*cols, sizeof(double));
    char *token, *text = malloc(len+1);
    strcpy(text, Text);
    int i, j;
    token = text;
    for(i=0;i<*cols;++i){
        for(j=0;j<2;++j){
            token = strtok(token, " ");
            //if(token == NULL)break;
            array[j][i]=strtod(token, NULL);
            token = NULL;
        }
    }
    free(text);
    return array;
}

int main(){
    char *source = "9 0.1 10 0.2 5 1.3 400 0.4 53 0.5 6 0.6";
    int r, c, cols;
    double **array;
    array = fillMatrix(&cols, source);
    for(r = 0; r < 2; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols ; ++c){
            printf(" %4g ", array[r][c]);
            if(c == cols - 1){
                printf("\n");
            } else {
                printf("|");
            }
        }
    }
    free(array[0]);
    free(array[1]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OfirAttia if you use MSVC , Try to at the beginning of the block of variable declarations. and you use int Instead of bool.